# Multiple FormArrays on Reactive form

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular, working on a small project. I completed the UI for the component and that is fine. I'm using reactive form.

```
this.questionForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      question : ['',[Validators.required]],
      options : this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.control({value:'',disabled:false},[Validators.required]),
        this._formBuilder.control({value:'',disabled:false},[Validators.required])
      ]),
      answers : this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.control({value:'',disabled:false}),
        this._formBuilder.control({value:'',disabled:false})
      ])

    })
```

And this is UI part where I'm facing this problem

```
<div formArrayName="options" class="form-group col-sm-6" *ngFor="let option of options.controls;let i=index;let temp=option as FormGroup">
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <div class="input-group-text">

                                        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" value="some" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="option.invalid && option.touched" [placeholder]="'option '+(i+1)">
                                    
                                </div>
                                <button class="text-danger remove-btn" (click)="removeOption(i)" *ngIf="enableRmBtn">X</button>
                            </div>
                            
                            <small *ngIf="option.invalid && option.touched" class="text-danger">Oops!! Cannot be an empty option</small>
                        </div>
```

The text input is working fine, but for implementing the checkbox I have no idea how to achieve it.I cannot give the same value for the formControlName for checkbox input. I just want the checkboxes that are select by the user.

Hoping for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue in check box can you explain little more?

Comment: The formControlName is same as the text input. So it's not working.The checkbox value is reflected for the text input also like true or false as the value of text input which should not be.

Comment: Instead of using same control for why can't you create array of formGroup?

Comment: Okay I will make try with that. Thank you

Comment: Np Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a3ye5v?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really helpful